# Computer randomly sees two networks after cold boot?

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-8.1, home-networking

Most of the time, when I reboot my Dell with Windows 8.1, I get a "limited connectivity" warning and notice that it has two network locations. There should only be one. I usually disable and re-enable the connection to fix it, but I want to know why this is happening. This is a wired connection with only one NIC in the machine. What could cause this? This is on a simple home network. All other machines are fine and don't show this behavior. Thanks.[image]

Comment: You probably have more than one DHCP server. Perhaps your modem has a built-in router, is connected LAN-to-LAN to your router, and you left DHCP enabled in the router.

Comment: Only one DHCP is on the network. This is the only computer with this occasional issue.